# Connecting to Oracle DB using python results in cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, python-2.7, oracle11g

I'm using python to connect to my school's oracle DB to execute few queries.

These are the steps I tired.

```
1) pip install cx_Oracle.
2) Downloaded oracle instant client 12.2 for mac.
3) Moved the downloaded files to /usr/local/lib.
4) When I executed the below script, I get the following error.
```

Note: I'm able to connect to the DB using SQL developer and execute the SQL queries manually. It's only with with the python script, I get the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oracle.py", line 30, in <module>
    db = DB()
  File "oracle.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.conn = cx_Oracle.connect(CONN_STR)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact



import cx_Oracle
    CONN_INFO = {
        'host': 'xxxxxx@gmu.edu',
        'port':  1630,
        'user': 'username',
        'psw':  'password',
        'service': 'PORTALSRV'}

    CONN_STR = '{user}/{psw}@{host}:{port}/{service}'.format(**CONN_INFO)

    class DB:
        def __init__(self):
            self.conn = cx_Oracle.connect(CONN_STR)


    QUERY = '''
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            EMPLOYEES
    '''

    def query(self, query, params=None):
            cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            result = cursor.execute(query, params).fetchall()
            cursor.close()
            return result


    db = DB()
    result = db.query(QUERY)

    print(result)
```